# Varias urlS para parser

Tags: kotlin, parsear

Tengo un array de url el cual quiero parsear ¿como puedo conseguirlo?.

```
         class FragNoJug : Fragment() {

    private val TAG = "MainActivity"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        retainInstance = true

        requestJsonObject()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false)

        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Partidos Pendientes"

        val miTexto: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Grupo)
        miTexto.setText(R.string.list_juveniles)

        return view
    }

    private fun requestJsonObject() {

        val queue = newRequestQueue(activity)

        val arr = listOf(
                "https://rafelcf.000webhostapp.com/rafel_cf/1.php",
                "https://rafelcf.000webhostapp.com/rafel_cf/2.php")

        arr.forEach {

           val url = (it)

           val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener { response ->
                val builder = GsonBuilder()
                val mGson = builder.create()

                val items: List<ModelJor>
                items = Arrays.asList(*mGson.fromJson(response, Array<ModelJor>::class.java))

                val filtro = items.filter { it.estadoPartido == "Pendiente" && it.fecha != ""}

                recyclerView!!.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity!!, 1)

                val adapter = AdapNJ(activity!!, filtro)
                recyclerView!!.adapter = adapter

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

            }, Response.ErrorListener { error -> Log.d(TAG, "Error " + error.message) })
            queue.add(stringRequest)
        }
    }
}
```

Alguna solucion?

Comment: Es esto posible?

Comment: Estás usando una lista (listOf) y tratas de recorrerla como si fuese un mapa (hashOf). Además no muestras el código completo.  Para recorrer la lista podrías usar:  

for(arr in arreglo){
      println("${arr}");
}

Comment: cambiado post 1 con el codigo completo

Comment: Pues estoy igual, con el for solo memuestra 1 url, y lo que quiero es que me muestre todas

Comment: ¿Qué error te arroja en la consola? Por lo que veo quieres obtener un JSON de esas ligas. Después parsear para obtener  información de estadoPartido y su fecha. Pero no índicas qué error ocurre o problema se presenta.

Comment: No hay ningun error lo que ocurre es que solo muestra una url, y me gustaria que mostrara todas. Todos los json en el mismo recyclerView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno espero ayudar a quien tenga que hacer algo asi, esta es la solucion:

```
fun getPendientes() {

        doAsync {

            for(num in 1..30) {

                val arr = arrayOf(
                        "http://www.url$num")

                arr.forEach {

                    val jsonText = URL(it).readText()

                    val jsonArray = JSONArray(jsonText)
                    for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {

                        val pendientes = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i)

                        val nomLocal = pendientes.getString("nomLocal")
                        val resulLocal = pendientes.getString("resulLocal")
                        val escudoLocal = pendientes.getString("escudoLocal")
                        val nomVisitante = pendientes.getString("nomVisitante")
                        val resulVisitante = pendientes.getString("resulVisitante")
                        val escudoVisitante = pendientes.getString("escudoVisitante")
                        val fecha = pendientes.getString("fecha")
                        val hora = pendientes.getString("hora")
                        val estadoPartido = pendientes.getString("estadoPartido")
                        val abreviaturaEstado = pendientes.getString("abreviaturaEstado")

                        modelPendientes.add(ModelPendientes(nomLocal, resulLocal, escudoLocal,
                                nomVisitante, resulVisitante, escudoVisitante, fecha, hora, estadoPartido,abreviaturaEstado))

                        val filtro = modelPendientes
                                .filter {it ->
                                        it.abreviaturaEstado == "P" ||
                                        it.abreviaturaEstado == "A" ||
                                        it.abreviaturaEstado == "S" &&
                                        it.fecha != ""
                                }

                        uiThread {
                            /*val filtro = modelPendientes.filter { it.abreviaturaEstado == "A" ||
                                    it.abreviaturaEstado == "S" || it.abreviaturaEstado == "P" && it.fecha != ""*/
                            //}
                            recyclerView!!.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity!!, 1)
                            adapter = PendientesAdapter(filtro, activity!!)
                            recyclerView!!.adapter = adapter
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```